# SWIFT UITableView - Multiple Rows in prototype cell segue to another UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I really have no idea what to search for with regards to this question and my search tries yielded not much help so I figure I'll give this post a shot.

I have a prototype cell that will have THREE ROWS. What I want to have happen is have a segue from each of those rows show another UITableView - but i'm hoping to keep the number of view controllers to a minimum so i'm hoping this can be achieved with only one tableViewController.

For example, the 1st row is "Outer Diameter (OD)", 2nd row is "Weight", and 3rd row is "Inner Diameter (ID)". These are defined as constants under my class declaration of the TableViewController file.

I have a segue (Modally) from the above TableViewController to a second TableViewController, for which I created a new file for it. I defined the OD, Weight, and ID values in this file as constants under my class declaration.

Is there any way to achieve this for when the user clicks the OD row it will only show the values/constants I defined for OD in the second view controller, as well as only show the Weight and ID constants for when the user clicks on those rows, respectively? My confusion is how to link the two TableViewControllers so they can interact with each other...but i'm not sure if this is even at all possible. My code thus far are as follows:

TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER 1:

```
import UIKit

class CapacitiesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let capacityParameters = ["O.D", "Weight", "I.D"]

@IBAction func cancelSelection(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 125.0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return capacityParameters.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // init return type of cell
    var returnCell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.section == 0 { // you can also check for section with section.index
        returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("capacitiesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let capacityID = capacityParameters[indexPath.row]
        returnCell.textLabel?.text = capacityID

    return returnCell

    } else {

        returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return returnCell

    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if section == 0 {
        return "Casing Specification"
    } else {
        return "Dimension & Strength"
    }
}
```

VIEW CONTROLLER 2:

```
import UIKit

class CasingSelectionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let casingOD = ["114.3", "127.0", "139.7", "168.3" , "177.8", "193.7", "219.1", "244.5", "247.6", "273.1", "298.4", "298.4", "339.7", "406.4", "473.0", "508"]

let casingWeight114 = ["14.14", "15.63", "17.26", "20.09", "22.47", "24.70", "26.34", "27.97"]
let casingWeight127 = ["17.11", "19.35", "22.32", "26.79", "31.85", "34.53", "35.86"]
let casingWeight139 = ["20.83", "23.07", "25.30", "29.76", "34.23", "39.28", "44.20", "48.51", "52.53", "56.55", "60.27", "64.14"]
let casingWeight168 = ["19.34", "25.30", "29.76", "32.74", "35.71", "38.69", "41.66", "43.15", "47.62", "50.59"]
let casingWeight177 = ["25.30", "29.76", "34.23", "38.69", "43.16", "47.62", "52.09", "56.55"]
let casingWeight193 = ["35.72", "39.29", "44.20", "50.15", "58.04"]
let casingWeight219 = ["35.72", "41.67", "47.62", "53.57", "59.53"]
let casingWeight244 = ["48.07", "53.57", "59.53", "64.73", "69.94", "79.62"]
let casingWeight247 = ["88.09"]
let casingWeight273 = ["48.74", "60.27", "67.71", "75.90", "82.59"]
let casingWeight298 = ["56.54", "62.50", "69.94", "80.35", "89.28", "96.72", "105.65"]
let casingWeight339 = ["71.43", "81.10", "90.78", "101.19", "107.15"]
let casingWeight406 = ["96.73", "111.61", "125.01", "162.21"]
let casingWeight473 = ["108.76", "116.06", "130.00", "143.59"]
let casingWeight508 = ["139.89", "158.49", "197.93"]

let id114 = ["103.886", "102.921", "101.600", "99.568", "97.180", "95.300", "93.900", "92.400"]
let id127 = ["115.824", "114.148", "111.963", "108.610", "104.800", "104.800", "102.718", "101.600"]
let id139 = ["127.305", "125.730", "124.257", "121.361", "118.618", "114.300", "111.150", "107.950", "104.800", "101.600", "98.450", "95.520"]
let id168 = ["158.800", "155.800", "153.600", "152.100", "150.300", "148.700", "147.000", "146.300", "144.100", "142.100"]
let id177 = ["166.065", "163.982", "161.696", "159.410", "157.074", "154.788", "152.502", "150.368"]
let id193 = ["178.400", "177.000", "174.700", "171.900", "168.300"]
let id219 = ["205.664", "203.632", "201.193", "198.700", "197.400"]
let id244 = ["228.630", "226.590", "224.410", "222.380", "220.500", "216.790"]
let id247 = ["217.400"]
let id273 = ["258.877", "255.270", "252.730", "250.190", "247.904"]
let id298 = ["283.200", "281.500", "279.400", "276.300", "273.600", "271.300", "268.800"]
let id339 = ["322.961", "320.421", "317.881", "315.341", "313.614"]
let id406 = ["387.350", "384.150", "381.254", "373.075"]
let id473 = ["454.000", "453.500", "450.900", "448.400"]
let id508 = ["485.750", "482.600", "475.742"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

/*
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to `ViewController2.swift` and declare following

```
enum Data
{
    case OuterDiameter
    case Weight
    case Innerdiameter
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { // Or sub class of UITableViewController

    var selectedData:Data!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    switch self.selectedData {
        case .OuterDiameter :
          //arrData = fill outer data
          break
        case .Weight :
          //arrData = fill weight
          break
        case .Innerdiameter :
          //arrData = fill inner data
          break
    }
    tblview.reloadData()
    } 
}
```

Now in `ViewController1.swift`

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { // Or sub class of UITableViewController

var selectedOption:Data!

// ............

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        selectedOption = Data.OuterDiameter
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        selectedOption == Data.Weight
    }
    else {
        selectedOption = Data.Innerdiameter;
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewController2", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    let view2 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
    view2.selectedData = selectedOption
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your post! I will give this a shot once I'm home from work and let you know how it goes

Comment: when i enter the switch cases in my viewDidLoad it gives me an error "enum case 'OuterDiameter' not found in type Data!"...could this be related at all to the fact that i used a tableViewController rather than using a viewController with tableView placed on top?

Answer (score 1):

All this isn't that complex.Do the following.

- In First viewController As you have said "I have a segue (Modally) from the above TableViewController to a second TableViewController" give this segue an identifier .
- On second ViewController Add a property like current selection for the type of row selected in your first viewncontroller.
- In First viewController In your didselectrow method set the current selection to a variable and then implement

> (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

- Here get your view controller from segue and set the property to the current selection
- In your secondViewController's ViewWillAppear or any other appropriate method load the data according to your currently selected property.

Comment: thank you imran for your answer. One question I have is what do you mean by adding a property like current selection for the type of row selected in my first view controller?

Comment: Yes right ,that can be string or enum or whatever you like

Comment: Hi Imran, I believe what you're saying is what Cute Angel mentioned in their answer to this post. However, I can't get the switch to work...getting the error "enum case 'OuterDiameter' not found in type Data!". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Swift version.

You can add tags to you buttons in the custom cell (you subclassed it, gave it identifier and if it's a nib you registered subclass?) then in cellForRowAtIndexPath -

```
cell.youButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.youButton.addTarget(self, action: "youMethod", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

Comment: Thank you Elkhan this will come in handy when I'm at the stage where i'll have a button in my cell!